# Cluster long/lat points with varying distance

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I want to be able to cluster long/lat points, where each long/lat point has a different reachability radius which shouldn't be violated

Assuming you have one long/lat pair as starting point *x* with reachability radius R1, i would like to be able to create a cluster with size Z, where the starting point is included. Furthermore, every point which is a candidate for this cluster should not have its reachability radius violated.

This means that even though point *y* is within point *x*'s reachability radius, it should not be included if its reachability radius cannot reach point *x*.

I thought i about bruteforcing this, but this is not very efficient(exponential). Therefore, I've looked at the DBSCAN algorithm, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem as the epsilon/distance is fixed.

Is there any obvious solution/algorithm that I'm missing, or is this just in-efficient to solve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use DBSCAN, by changing the function that returns the neighbor points of a given point with your check (namely there should be a symmetric reachability, given the reachability associated between two points), instead of using the check with eps?

Comment: That is actually a really good idea. Furthermore, it should also verify that the starting point can be reached before considering it at all, otherwise it is just noise.

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN is very adaptable. See the method **Generalized DBSCAN** for a discussion. Essentially, you can define a neighbor predicate such as "both are mutually reachable" and then run DBSCAN with this modified neighborhood.

Also you may want to look into OPTICS and HDBSCAN*, both improve over DBSCAN.